# Как получить id созданных записей

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Есть таблица postgresql `payments_approval_history`
В таблицу вносятся сразу несколько записей, необходимо получить id этих записей без доп запроса чтобы не увеличивать впустую счетчик id. Сейчас я умею такое реализовывать только с использованием цикла (пробегаемся по каждой записи и вносим отдельно:

```
query_a_h = """
    INSERT INTO payments_approval_history (
        payment_id,
        status_id,
        user_id,
        approval_sum
    )
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)
    RETURNING payment_id, confirm_id;"""

values_p_a_h = [
    (26, 2, 2, 2),
    (27, 2, 2, 3),
    (80, 2, 2, 4)
]

tmp = []
for i in range(len(values_p_a_h)):
    cursor.execute(query_a_h, 
                   [
                    values_p_a_h[i][0], 
                    values_p_a_h[i][1], 
                    values_p_a_h[i][2], 
                    values_p_a_h[i][3]
                    ])
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    tmp.append(results)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
print(tmp)
```

В интернетах я нашёл `executemany`, но он не может возвращать ничего `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch` и ничего не записывает, пока из запроса не удалишь `RETURNING payment_id, confirm_id`
В документации `psycopg2` говорится, что лучше использовать `execute_batch`, но на выходе я получаю только последнее значение из всего списка.

**Мой вопрос**: Какая практика лучшая в случае, когда необходимо внести строк 10-30 и получить их id обратно?

Comment: INSERT .. VALUES допускает multirow syntax (несколько блоков данных, для нескольких записей сразу). https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html

Comment: Всё так! Но как получить id полученных записей в таком случае?С запросом в БД вопрос нет, вопрос про то, как получить ответ в питоне

Comment: Что значит как? расширить RETURNING и добавить в выходной набор поля, которые позволят однозначно идентифицировать, какой записи какое из сгенерированных значений соответствует. Если payment_id однозначно идентифицирует платёж, то вообще ничего не требуется, иначе надо привлекать дополнительные значения вставляемых записей.

Comment: ```executemany``` не возвращает данные, я писал про это  В ```execute``` необходимо добавлять по одной записи. В ```execute_batch``` возвращается только последняя запись. Делать десятки запросов для записи данных я думал не рационально от этого и вопрос, как одним запросом и записать всё и получить все id

Comment: *В execute необходимо добавлять по одной записи.* А можно, я не поверю? Потому как я что-то больше доверяю документации... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html `cursor.fetchall()` выгребает ВСЕ возвращённые записи и возвращает итератор - вот и перебирайте его...

Comment: а где в документации сказано, что одним запросом я добавляю сразу несколько записей?

Comment: cursor.execute в принципе не знает, что там выполняют его запросы и сколько их. По итогам выполнения переданного задания сервер возвращает курсору отчёт по выполненному запросу, или по каждому из запросов, если их несколько. Каждый отчёт может содержать либо не содержать записи. Если содержит - их может быть ни одной, одна или несколько. Если INSERT добавляет одну или несколько записей - возвращается статус выполнения. Если он содержит RETURNING - то возвращаются и статус, и все возвращённые RETURNING записи. Которые можно получить так же, как и результат обычного SELECT.

Comment: Я понял в чем дело, чтобы передать сразу несколько строк в ```VALUES``` необходимо создать некую другую конструкцию, не список в списке.  Вот такую вот конструкцию ```','.join(['(' + ', '.join(map(str, item)) + ')' for item in values_p_a_h])```. Правильно ли я понимаю, что моё решение противоречит правилу из документации? https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#:~:text=stress%20this%20point%3A-,Warning,-Never%2C%20never

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31520928/10138734

Comment: В общем что я понял, так это то, что в конструкции ```query_a_h``` я должен использовать конструктор для получения структуры по типу ```VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s), (%s,%s,%s,%s), (%s,%s,%s,%s)```, а в ```values_p_a_h``` должен быть одномерный список, то есть не ```values_p_a_h = [(26, 2, 2, 2), (27, 2, 2, 3), (80, 2, 2, 4)]``` а : ```values_p_a_h = [26, 2, 2, 2, 27, 2, 2, 3, 80, 2, 2, 4]```. Спасибо! Что-то простые вещи сложно доходят

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
import psycopg2 as pg

from psycopg2.extras import execute_values

values_p_a_h = [
    (26, 2, 2, 2),
    (27, 2, 2, 3),
    (80, 2, 2, 4)
]

with pg.connect('<connection string>') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        try:
            a_h_id = execute_values(
                cur,
                """
                INSERT INTO payments_approval_history (
                    payment_id,
                    status_id,
                    user_id,
                    approval_sum
                )
                VALUES %s on conflict do nothing 
                RETURNING payment_id, confirm_id;
                """,
                values_p_a_h,
                template="""(%s::int, %s::int, %s::int, %s::int)""",
                page_size=len(values_p_a_h), # вот тут возможны варианты. По умолчанию 500
                fetch=True
            )
        except Exception:
            conn.rollback()
            raise
        else:
            conn.commit()
```

Comment: Можете, ещё в этой теме, ответить, пожалуйста? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1537582/postgresql-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8e%d1%8e-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83

Answer (score -1):

Для решения моей проблемы с отправкой множества значений нужно было использовать `execute_values` (`from psycopg2.extras import execute_values`)
[Ссылка на документацию](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values)
Большое спасибо **[Акину](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina)** за подсказки
Создал функцию, которая помогает мне создать запрос

```
def get_db_dml_query(action, table, columns, subquery=";"):
    query = None
    if action == 'UPDATE':
        # Список столбцов в SET
        expr_set = ', '.join([f"{col} = c.{col}" for col in columns[1:]])
        # Список столбцов для таблицы "с"
        expr_s_tab = str(columns).replace('\'', '').replace('"', '')
        # Выражение для WHERE
        expr_where = result = f"c.{columns[0]} = t.{columns[0]}"
        # Конструктор запроса
        query = f"{action} {table} AS t SET {expr_set} FROM (VALUES %s) AS c {expr_s_tab} WHERE {expr_where} {subquery}"

    elif action == 'INSERT INTO':
        # Кортеж колонок переводим в строки и удаляем кавычки
        expr_cols = str(columns).replace('\'', '').replace('"', '')
        # Конструктор запроса
        query = f"{action} {table} {expr_cols} VALUES  %s {subquery}"

    return query
```

Сама запись в БД выглядит вот так:

```
# Запись в payments_approval_history
action_p_a_h = 'INSERT INTO'
table_p_a_h = 'payments_approval_history'
columns_p_a_h = ('payment_id', 'status_id', 'user_id', 'approval_sum')
subquery = " RETURNING payment_id, confirm_id;"
query_a_h = get_db_dml_query(action_p_a_h, table_p_a_h, columns_p_a_h, subquery)
values_p_a_h = [
    (26, 2, 2, 2),
    (27, 2, 2, 3),
    (80, 2, 2, 4)
]
a_h_id = execute_values(cursor, query_a_h, values_p_a_h, fetch=True)
conn.commit()
```

`a_h_id` - возвращает двумерный список с нужной информацией

Comment: Да ни в коем случае

Comment: Почему "Да ни в коем случае"?

Comment: Потому, что вы пытаетесь придумать велосипед после автомобиля, создавая форматирующие запросы функции. Почитайте документацию по библиотеке которую пытаетесь использовать.

Comment: Мне удобно пользоваться этой функцией, она делает тоже, что и в вашем коде, соглашусь, что может проще всегда писать запрос текстом. Спасибо за ваш комментарий. Заставляет задуматься

Comment: Понимание бесполезности подобных действий приходит с практикой.

Comment: Вы не особо помогаете своей токсичностью, если вы устали от тупых вопросов - игнорируйте их. У меня, например не у кого спросить такие вещи. И ладно бы это была ваша работа и вы выгорали - понимаю, ничего не остаётся, кроме, как огрызаться

Comment: В данном случае огрызаетесь Вы. Я же просто дал Вам добрый совет читать документацию по библиотеке, которую используете и по-хорошему поделился мнением о тщетности усилий подобных вашим. Так что кто из нас более токсичен, я со своими наставлениями или Вы со своей юношеской ершистостью, это большой вопрос.

Comment: Кроме того, комментируя Ваш код я помогаю не Вам. Если честно, то Вы мне абсолютно безразличны. Я предостерегаю тех, кто захочет пойти по этому пути и использовать подобные решения.

Comment: Спасибо за честность!

Comment: Я не против доброго совета, просто он не читается, как добрый и зачем ставить минус, на сам минус пофиг, просто это реально,как нападок читается? Я увидел ваш пост, он пригодился, просто он был дан позже чем я нашёл хоть какое-то решение. Я его не откинул