# Как быстро распарсить много json файлов на python?

Tags: python, json, парсер

Стоит задача распарсить 8000 Json файлов, объем всего этого добра ~ 8 гигов. Нужно вытащить нужную информацию и записать в базу. На файл уходит по 2 секунды. То есть на все файлы ~5 часов. Ищу решение как сделать быстрее, учитывая, что i\o biund операция.
Прошу всех неравнодушных и не душных подсказать куда копать!

Вот часть кода

```
for filename in os.listdir(download_dir):
    if filename.endswith('.json'):
        with open(os.path.join(download_dir, filename), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as j_f:
            try:
                data = json.load(j_f)
                companies_to_create = []
                for d in data:
                    if isinstance(d, dict):
                        inn = d.get('inn', '')
                        kpp = d.get('kpp', '')
                        name = d.get('name', '')
                        address_ul = d.get('data', {}).get('СвРегОрг', {}).get('АдрРО', '')
                        sv_okved = d.get('data', {}).get('СвОКВЭД', {})
                        if sv_okved:
                            sv_okved_dop = sv_okved.get('СвОКВЭДДоп', [])
                            for sv in sv_okved_dop:
                                if isinstance(sv, dict) and sv.get('КодОКВЭД', '').startswith('96'):
                                    okved = sv.get('КодОКВЭД', '')
                                    if not "Хабаровск" in address_ul:
                                        existing_company = Company.objects.filter(inn=inn).first()
                                        if not existing_company:
                                            company = Company(
                                                name=name,
                                                okved=okved,
                                                inn=inn,
                                                kpp=kpp,
                                                address_ul=address_ul,
                                            )
                                            companies_to_create.append(company)
                Company.objects.bulk_create(companies_to_create)
```

Comment: Замерьте время обработки без обращений к `Company`. Думаю станет раз 10-20 быстрее. Это база данных тормозит. Индексы и всё такое.

Comment: Если представите пару примеров, можно попробовать помочь, если, по каким-то причинам это невозможно, копайте в сторону `jmespath`, и еще не плохо бы знать какую БД используете

Comment: `existing_company = Company.objects.filter(inn=inn).first()` - ¿Это у вас тут запрос выполняется на каждой итерации трех вложенных циклов?

Comment: @user7860670
Нет, это проверка, чтобы не было дубликатов. То есть если unique=True поставить на данное поле, то почему то в базу пихалась всего одна запись и самая первая. Да и с другими полями так же.
Выкрутился таким образом.

Comment: @Namerek, postgres 12, как я могу предоставить фрагмент json файла?

Comment: Ну к примеру загрузить куда-то один из 8000 json файлов. Ну и структуру таблицы описать, ту, в которую внести данные хотите.

Comment: Давайте так. Если до завтра не найдете решение, я завтра утром попробую набросать Вам решение. Смотрите `psycopg2` `execute_values`. Ну и индексы конечно не забывайте. Вот тут пример гляньте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1536201/397399

Comment: Если в БД не идут новые записи из нескольких скриптов одновременно и пополняются только отсюда, то перед началом всех циклов получите из БД одним запросом все существующие ИНН, положите их в set и внутри цикла проверяйте уже не запросами, а просто смотрите in в этом сете.

Comment: А если все таки вероятность что инн там появятся из других источников во время работы, то я бы все равно сделал бы себе set, заполнил при старте из БД, а внутри цикла бы тогда если в set нет перепроверял отсутствие по БД и добавлял в set если нашел

Comment: @Namerek, https://disk.yandex.ru/d/agM3NOOFsNZMQA - ссылка на json файл.
Пока из всего, что нарыл это советы использовать треддинг, asyncio и aiofiles. И еще сама конструкция с кучей вложенных циклов мне самому не нравится. Хочу попробовать заюзать pandas, чтобы избавиться от такой вложенность и возможно это еще выиграло бы немного времени.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте начнем с уточнения задачи. Если я правильно понял, то Вам нужно выбрать все компании зарегистрированные не в Хабаровске и имеющие дополнительные ОКВЭД начинающиеся на `96` (при этом сами ОКВЭД не нужны)

*Если ошибся в формулировке задачи, поправьте, что-то придумаем*

Самая главная, на мой взгляд, ошибка заключается в том, что Вы для каждого найденного ДопОКВЭД начинающегося с `96` пытаетесь создать запись, проверяя не создавалась ли она ранее.

Предлагаю несколько изменить такой порядок:

`pip install pydantic --upgrade`

```py
import json
from pydantic import BaseModel, TypeAdapter
# В этом примере используется pydantic >= 2.0
# Для более ранних версий код будет слегка отличаться


# В данном случае я искусственно увеличил размер набора данных, чтобы воспроизвести Вашу ситуацию. 

with open(r'C:\Users\karpo\Downloads\00001.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f) * 8000

# Тем не менее я предлагаю Вам прежде чем пытаться записывать 
# данные в БД собрать данные в одну переменную и подготовить данные для записи.

class Firm(BaseModel):
    inn: str = ''
    kpp: str = ''
    name: str = ''
    address: str = ''

    # Добавление этих методов даст возможность создать множество
    # (объект типа set) подобных объектов
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.inn)
        # В данном случае объекты будут считаться идентичными если их ИНН равны

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__hash__() == other.__hash__()

# Создадим функцию которая будет возвращать нам генератор только нужных нам элементов
def get_useful(firm_list: list[dict]):
    for firm in firm_list:
        address = ''

        try:
            if 'Хабаровск' in (address := firm['data']['СвРегОрг']['АдрРО']):
                continue
        except KeyError:
            pass

        for item in firm['data'].get('СвОКВЭД', dict()).get('СвОКВЭДДоп', []):
            if isinstance(item, dict) and item['КодОКВЭД'].startswith('96'):
                
                yield Firm.model_validate(
                    firm | {
                        'address': address
                    }
                )
                break

# Далее создадим множество подходящих записей и преобразуем его в кортеж данных для записи в БД

data_to_db = TypeAdapter(tuple[Firm]).dump_python(tuple(set(get_useful(data))))
```

---

```sql
-- так как структуру БД вы не предоставили, пришлось пофантазировать

create table okved_test (
    inn varchar primary key ,
    kpp varchar,
    name text,
    address text
);
```

---

```py
import psycopg2 as pg
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values

with pg.connect('<connection string>') as conn, conn.cursor() as cur:
    execute_values(
        cur,
        """
        insert into okved_test (inn, kpp, name, address) values %s on conflict do nothing 
        """,
        data_to_db,
        template="""(
        %(inn)s,
        %(kpp)s,
        %(name)s,
        %(address)s
        )""",
        page_size=10000
    )
    conn.commit()
```

Вот что получилось из Вашего `json`

| inn | kpp | name | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0103007142 | 010101001 | ООО "КАСКАД" | 385009,Республика Адыгея,город Майкоп, ул. Привокзальная, 331. |
| 0104007787 | 010401001 | ТУЛЬСКОЕ ПО | 385009,Республика Адыгея,город Майкоп, ул. Привокзальная, 331. |
| 1643000792 | 164301001 | КП АЗНАКАЕВСКОГО РПУ БОН | ,420054,,, Казань г,, Владимира Кулагина ул, 1,, |
| 0105037625 | 010501001 | ООО "МОНОЛИТ" | 385009,Республика Адыгея,город Майкоп, ул. Привокзальная, 331. |
| 0105012701 | 010501001 | АО "МАЙКОПНОРМАЛЬ" | 385009,Республика Адыгея,город Майкоп, ул. Привокзальная, 331. |
| 0105034293 | 010501001 | ООО "АНИТ" | 385009,Республика Адыгея,город Майкоп, ул. Привокзальная, 331. |
| 0105035875 | 231201001 | ООО "МАЙКОПГИПССТРОЙ" | ,350020,,, Краснодар г,, Коммунаров ул, д 235,, |
| 0103006420 | 010101001 | ООО "АНТЕЯ" | 385009,Республика Адыгея,город Майкоп, ул. Привокзальная, 331. |
| 0105005341 | 010501001 | ООО "НАРТ" | 385009,Республика Адыгея,город Майкоп, ул. Привокзальная, 331. |
| 0105031260 | 010501001 | ООО "МИР ЦЕНТР" | 385009,Республика Адыгея,город Майкоп, ул. Привокзальная, 331. |
| 0105004595 | 010501001 | ТПП РА | 385009,Республика Адыгея,город Майкоп, ул. Привокзальная, 331. |
| 0105029550 | 010501001 | ООО "ЮГ-КОМПЛЕКТ" | 385009,Республика Адыгея,город Майкоп, ул. Привокзальная, 331. |
| 0105027730 | 010501001 | ООО ФИРМА "ЦЕНТР" | 385009,Республика Адыгея,город Майкоп, ул. Привокзальная, 331. |

Comment: Превосходно! Спасибо!
Попытаюсь вникнуть в это.

Comment: @ЗахарЕлисеев, спрашивайте, если что-то будет непонятно.